# How to block-sort rows of text file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a bar-separated text file that looks like this:

```
stringC|rest-of-lineC3
stringC|rest-of-lineC1
stringC|rest-of-lineC2
stringA|rest-of-lineA2
stringA|rest-of-lineA1
stringB|rest-of-lineB4
stringB|rest-of-lineB1
stringB|rest-of-lineB3
stringB|rest-of-lineB2
```

I need to block-sort it by the string before the `|` without doing secondary sort of what comes after the bar. So the example below SHOULD be sorted into:

```
stringA|rest-of-lineA2
stringA|rest-of-lineA1
stringB|rest-of-lineB4
stringB|rest-of-lineB1
stringB|rest-of-lineB3
stringB|rest-of-lineB2
stringC|rest-of-lineC3
stringC|rest-of-lineC1
stringC|rest-of-lineC2
```

but NOT into:

```
stringA|rest-of-lineA1
stringA|rest-of-lineA2
stringB|rest-of-lineB1
...
```

Is there a way of doing this in a bash script using `sort` or any other commands?

How can I get the same result as above in case the original file is not in blocks, i.e. it looks something like this:

```
stringC|rest-of-lineC3
stringA|rest-of-lineA2
stringC|rest-of-lineC1
stringA|rest-of-lineA1
stringB|rest-of-lineB4
stringB|rest-of-lineB1
stringC|rest-of-lineC2
stringB|rest-of-lineB3
stringB|rest-of-lineB2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sort with `-s` option for stable

```
sort -st'|' -k1,1 file
```

initial blocks doesn't matter, should work for both.